# Log just the keys of JSON request body

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot controller which accepts a JSON request as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/v1/myapi"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void addItem(@Valid @RequestBody Item item) {
}
```

I want to log the request I get to the controller. However, I just want to log the keys, and not the values, since there might be some PII and stuff. There will be nested objects in the request as well.

Is there an easy way to do this without having to parse / iterate through the request? Even if there is a library to do this, I'm fine.

Comment: In that case you need to change your method as `addItem(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> body)` and print body.keySet().
Once you map your body in Item  class, you loose the information what was present in json as keys

Comment: Hey! is there any harm if you just write a recursive method that always looks up for keys and keep on adding those to a list?

Comment: Even if I have a map, I can't simply use keySet(). That won't go through the nested objects, will it? I would have to iterate through each of the objects manually and print it out, which I want to avoid if possible.